# Check if URL has anything after second "/" using javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, html

So I have a completely variable url:

www.whatever.com/something/pagename

I need something to happen on the homepage of the websites and not on any of the other pages. Sometimes the homepage has a "something" in the url and sometimes it doesn't, so I need to find out if "pagename" exists, whatever it may be.

all values in the url vary so i can't simply search for a string in the url..

Is this possible to do this using only JS / JQuery?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any code posted. [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Use `str.split('/')` to split it into an array, then you can access the array elements to find a particular component.

Comment: @Barmar - this may be a good idea but how would i find it without knowing its size, content or whether it's the second or the third item in the array?

Comment: What do you need to find? The question just says you need to know if there's anything after the second `/`. So you can just get the length of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split is the solution:

```
var exampleURL = "www.whatever.com/something/pagename";
var pageName = exampleURL.split("/")[2];

console.log(pageName);
//OUT -> pagename
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the URL and then check the length of the result.

```
var split_url = url.split('/');
if (split_url.length > 2) {
    // URL is like www.whatever.com/something/pagename...
} else {
    // URL is just www.whatever.com or www.whatever.com/something
}
```

Another way is with a regular expression that matches a URL with two slashes:

```
if (url.match(/\/.*\//)) {
    // URL contains two slashes
} else {
    // URL has at most one slash
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a regex check:

```
/^[^\/\s]*(\/\/)?[^\/\s]+\/[^\/\s]+[^\/]+\/[^\/\s]+$/.test('www.whatever.com/something/pagename')
```

demo:
https://regex101.com/r/vF1bH8/1

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really clear, but to answer the title literally https://jsfiddle.net/jgfeymk1/

```
function after2ndFSlash(inpu){
var pieces = inpu.split('/');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
    if(pieces.length>2){
    output.innerHTML += 'true<br/>';
  }
  else{
    output.innerHTML += 'false<br/>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that url string has protocol included ... `http(s)://` ... you can pass it to href of an `<a>` element and access the pathname property

```
var url ='http://www.whatever.com/something/pagename'

var a =  document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;

var pathParts = a.pathname.replace(/^\//,'').split('/');//["something","pagename"]
alert(pathParts[1]); //"pagename"
```